# @EnableDynamoDBRepositories using aws-sdk2 and springboot3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cloud9

I'm migrating my app to springboot3 which requires me to use aws-cloud3 and aws-sdk2.

I do use DynamoDB with `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories` and also using `DynamoDBMapperConfig` from sdk1.

@EnableDynamoDBRepositories is not creating the beans and also I didn't find an equivalent to DynamoDBMapperConfig in sdk2.

```
Error creating bean with name 'blackListedTokenRepository' defined in com.lanehealth.hsa.dynamo.BlackListedTokenRepository defined in @EnableDynamoDBRepositories declared on LocalHsaServerConfig: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dynamoDB-DynamoDBTemplate-amazonDynamoDB' while setting bean property 'dynamoDBOperations'
```

I want to see if there's a workaround to use `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories` using sdk2